# how to change Navbar based on role with jwt token reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I try to create a navbar which later will change after logging in based on user role, but after I tried it the navbar was successfully changed after login or logout, BUT if I should refresh the browser. so if i don't refresh the browser then the navbar won't change. how to solve it? here's the code of app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
import NavbarAwal from './Component/NavbarAwal';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import 'react-bootstrap';
import NavbarPembeli from './Component/NavbarUser';
import NavbarPenjual from './Component/NavbarPenjual';
import { login, register } from './View/UserFunctions';
import Routes from './Router';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Roles: "",
    };
  }
  render() {
    
    const token=localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
    if(token===null){
      return (
    <div id="root">
      <NavbarAwal/>
      <Routes/>
    </div>
      ) 
    }
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    if (decoded.Roles === "Penjual") {
      return (
        <div id="root">
          <NavbarPenjual/>
          <Routes/>
      </div>
      )
    } else if (decoded.Roles === "Pembeli") {
      return (
    <div id="root">
      <NavbarPembeli/>
      <Routes/>
    </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
      <div>
       <NavbarAwal/>
       <Routes/>
      </div>
      )
    } 
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I think you'll need to add the re-render logic in componentDidUpdate method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const token=localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  if (this.state !== decoded.Roles) {
    this.setState({Roles: decoded.Roles})
  }
}
```

And in your render logic, use `this.state.Roles` instead of `decoded.Roles`

Comment: still, the navbar still unchanged

Comment: change method params to `(prevProps, prevState)` and 
change `this.state !== decoded.Roles` to `prevState !== decoded.Roles`

Comment: still :( navbar still unchanged :'(